# Why does $\int_{-5}^{5}\sqrt{\ 1\ -\ \frac{x^2}{25}\ }\ dx$ evaluate in this way?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Wolfram Alpha is telling me the following statement is true, but doesn't provide steps to get from one half of the equation to another:

$$ \int_{-5}^{5}\sqrt{\ 1\ -\ \frac{x^2}{25}\ }\ dx\ =\ \left[ \ x\ \sqrt{1\ -\ \frac{x^2}{25}}\ \right|_{-5}^5 $$

I really need to know how to get from one expression to the other. Can anyone show me how?

Comment: Not a true equality.  The LHS is $\dfrac{5\pi}{2}$ and the RHS is $0$.  Can you provide a link to the Wolfram output?

Comment: Can you link to the Wolfram Alpha page?

Comment: An inverse sin function (or inverse cos function) has been dropped in translation.

Comment: Arcsine I think, but this should also be doable with trig sub so that there are no inverse trig functions.

Comment: Check this:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Integration_techniques/Trigonometric_Substitution

Comment: Here's a link to the original Wolfram Alpha input; you need access to the Step-by-step solution feature to see the above equality, though: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+%28+1+-+X^2+%2F25+%29^0.5+dx+from+-5+to+5

Comment: And here's image output of the Step-by-step solution from Wolfram Alpha; perhaps I read it incorrectly : http://imgur.com/7ToRjmK

Comment: The equation you have above cannot be true. The left side is the integral of a positive function over a non-empty interval. The right side is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\ \overbrace{\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{25}}}^u\  \overbrace{\Big( 1\, dx\Big) }^{dv} & = \overbrace{\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du}^\text{integration by parts} \\[10pt]
& = x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}} - \int x \cdot \frac{(-2x/25)}{2\sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{25}}}\, dx.
\end{align}
This last integral, taken from $-5$ to $5$, is not $0$, so the proposed equality,
$$
\int_{-5}^5 \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}} \, dx \overset{\huge\text{?}} = \left. x \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}} \, \right|_{-5}^5,
$$
is not true.

Comment: Well illustrated.

Comment: @NoChance : Thank you. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=5\int\cos(u)\,\mathrm{d}\sin(u)\tag{1}\\
&=5\int\cos^2(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2}\\
&=5\sin(u)\cos(u)-5\int\sin(u)\,\mathrm{d}\cos(u)\tag{3}\\
&=5\sin(u)\cos(u)+5\int\sin^2(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{4}\\[3pt]
&=\frac52\sin(u)\cos(u)+\frac52u+C\tag{5}\\[3pt]
&=\frac12x\,\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}+\frac52\sin^{-1}\left(\frac x5\right)+C\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x=5\sin(u)$
$(2)$: $\mathrm{d}\sin(u)=\cos(u)\,\mathrm{d}u$
$(3)$: integrate $(1)$ by parts
$(4)$: $\mathrm{d}\cos(u)=-\sin(u)\,\mathrm{d}u$
$(5)$: average $(2)$ and $(4)$
$(6)$: substitute $x=5\sin(u)$

Plug the limits into the integral
$$
\begin{align}
\left.\frac12x\,\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}+\frac52\sin^{-1}\left(\frac x5\right)\,\right|_{x=-5}^{x=+5}
&=\frac52\left(\frac\pi2-\left(-\frac\pi2\right)\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac52\pi
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that the expression within the integral is actually the equation for an ellipse, with radii of $5$ and $1$. The area for an ellipse is $$A=\pi (r_1 r_2)$$

Comment: And why is that so?? I don't think it is a circle at all...

Comment: @imranfat I made an error. Please see the edit

Comment: Makes sense....

Comment: @imranfat Haha, yeah, I'm getting tired. I'm actually surprised I missed that...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you got from the left hand side to the right hand side, as indicated by others. If we consider the function $y=\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}$
If you apply integration here, and substitute $x=5\sin t$ you and up integrating $5\cos^2t$ from $t$-values $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. Anti deriving yields $0.5t+0.25\sin2t$ and plugging in $t$-values gives $\frac{5\pi}{2}$. Can you go through the rudiments? Of course, as noted by another answer, we are really finding the area of a semi ellipse, so this can also be done without integration...